# I want to center whole parent block, but I want child block to be lefted. How can I do this?

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        O
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        O
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        O
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        O
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.parent {
    text-align: center;
}   

div.child {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Current Output Looks like this below**

```
O O O O
```

**If I shrink its page's width, it looks like this now**

```
O O O 
  O
```

**But I want it looks like this instead(lefted)**

```
O O O
O
```

If I add "float:left;" into **child block**, I see wide range of blank space in right side of **parent block** when it doesn' have enough space to show a **child block**.
I want the same range of blank space both on right and left side of **child blocks**

I want to keep whole **parent block** right in the middle centered.
But I want **child block** to be lefted.
How can I change my CSS?

**UPDATE(this keeps the same width of blank space on both left and right side of child blocks, but it shows child block in center when a child block comes to 2nd line )**

http://jsfiddle.net/P6Dsb/

See this. the blank spaces on left and right are not the same.
I always want it the same width even if I shrink the window size.
These 4 child block have to be centered.
[image: pic]

**This is perfect because it has the same width of blank space on both left side and right side of childs. But child comes in middle at 2nd line. It has to be lefted.**
[image]

**UPDATE PIC**

[image]

Comment: Looks like you want the first 3 blocks on the same row, that is quite different from what you describe in the text. Try this see if it matches your need: http://jsfiddle.net/bogdanbiv/PgLXu/
Same solution as the one provided by BwithLove.

Comment: I guess that you'll need to provide some info: **1)** what type of element do you need to center? (text is different from image).
Let me see if I understood: you need 2 divs, **1** for left (for childs) and **2** for other element?

Comment: @BogdanBiv Thanks! jsfiddle.net/P6Dsb/1 check this out please. if you shrink window width, you see wider blank space on right side of child blocks. I want it the same width as its right side. Is it possible?

Comment: @Fiskolin I have 2 elements such as parent and child here. I want parent to be centered in the page. But I want all child element to be lefted. When I shrink down or spread out the window size, I always want the same width of blank space on both left and right side of childs.

Comment: If you're searching for a way to get 2 elements, one at the top and one at the bottom, you need to do exactly 2 elements calling for same style, as [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/JrGJ6/)

Comment: @Fiskolin could you customize  and show with my original code? http://jsfiddle.net/P6Dsb/

Comment: @MKK [here you have](http://jsfiddle.net/P6Dsb/2/). You need to create another parent inside the 1st one for that, as an example. It's a HTML fault itself, not CSS.

Comment: @Fiskolin Thanks but child come appears in middle when it comes to 2nd line:(

Comment: That's because your window size, as [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/P6Dsb/4/)

Comment: @Fiskolin I want child come appears on left when it comes to 2nd line. Is it impossible unless I use float:left? But I don't want to use it because there will be different width of blank space on both left side and right side if I use it.

Comment: If you don't use `float`, **it will be applied in left automatically**. BUT, if you put it inside an element that has `text-align: center`, your text will be applied in center as well. If you need to align your text, **you need to set width to force the size of the div**. Clear? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way for example:

```
div.parent {

    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;        
}   

div.child {

    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[DEMO 1](http://jsbin.com/obOhOcek/2/edit)

**UPDATE**

I hope I understand what you mean...

What about this: [DEMO 2](http://jsbin.com/EQovera/2) (tested in chrome)

```
div.parent {

    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 10% 0 30%; /* NOTE THIS */
}

div.child {

    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

You can do this more elegant with [Media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Comment: Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/P6Dsb/1/ check this out please. if you shrink window width, you see wider blank space on right side of child blocks. I want it the same width as its right side. Is it possible?

Comment: There are.. or? I don`t understand what you mean... You can increase the width for example [see here](http://jsbin.com/obOhOcek/2) ... when you shrink the windows (tested in Chrome) then you have the same margin on left and right side...

Comment: I'm using firefox on Mac. Please see my update(UPDATE PIC) do you see way more blank space on right side of child elements??

Answer (score 1):

Use following css.

```
div.parent {
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100px; /*width as per your requirement*/
    max-width: 200px; /*width as per your requirement*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}   

div.child {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: @BwithLove Thanks! but the width changes all the time, because my page is designed with responsive design and its accessed with many devices.

Comment: You are specifying min and max width not fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

Just left align the text in the child divs.

```
div.child {
    display: inline-block; 
    text-align: left;
}
```